# iOS Swift XCTest accessing OTP from text message

Tags: ios, swift, automated-tests, xctest, xcuitest

I'm trying to test the login process for my application. an OTP is sent from a provider and I need to enter that OTP into a textfield.

I've opened the keyboard and seem to be able to access all the keys with

```
po app.keys
```

However the "from message 5555" where 5555 is the OTP code is not shown here. How can I click the "from message 5555" button

Comment: I presume this is for UI testing.

Comment: @JonReid Yes, sorry if that was not clear

Comment: I added a tag to make this clearer